# Через N время сменить картину

Tags: vue.js

Идея была написать slider, чтоб через N время сменилась картинка с текстом на другой слайд и т.д. по кругу и так же была возможность по dotnav листать слайды в перед и назад.
На JQ я бы быстро все сделал, а вот с Vue и использывая только его не выходит быстро.

Через N время в теги "li" написать класс active, а в предыдущем удалить и должно быть симитрично идти с dotnav. Кто сможет подсказать или помочь с этим? 
Всем спасибо кто откликнулся!

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue!',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Center of osteopatia and rehabilitation',
                    url_img: 'https://i.imgur.com/gQp3VSW.jpg',
                    info_block: [
                        {
                            incremental: '+800%',
                            description: 'Increasing the number of transactions from organic search results'
                        },
                        {
                            incremental: '+240%',
                            description: 'Raising your revenue'
                        }

                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'SLide 2',
                    url_img: 'https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/space-wallpaper-5.jpg',
                    info_block: [
                        {
                            incremental: '+140%',
                            description: 'Increasing the numb organic search results'
                        },
                        {
                            incremental: '+790%',
                            description: 'Raising your revenue'
                        }

                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: ' SLIDE 3',
                    url_img: 'https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/4433836-space-wallpapers.jpg',
                    info_block: [
                        {
                            incremental: '+110%',
                            description: 'Increasing the number of trans'
                        },
                        {
                            incremental: '+99%',
                            description: 'Raising your revenue'
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        },

        methods: {
            index_dotnav:function (index) {
                console.log(index);

            }


        }


    })
```

```css
    ul{
        padding-left: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .img-block,
    section > *,
    .uk-slideshow,
    .uk-slideshow > ul {
        height: 100vh !important;
    }

    .information-slide .uk-container {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block {
        top: 50%;
        left: 95%;

        z-index: 2;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block li a {
        background: #fff;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block li.active a {
        width: 13px;
        height: 13px;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block ul {
        align-items: center;
    }

    .slideshow .slideshow-items > li {
        display: none;
    }

    .slideshow .slideshow-items > li.active {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .slideshow .slideshow-items > li img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Тест</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.14/css/uikit.min.css"/>


</head>




<body>
<div id="app">
    <section>
        <div class="uk-child-width-1-2" uk-grid>
            <div>
                <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="slideshow">

                    <ul class="slideshow-items">

                        <li v-for="(item,index) in items"  :class="{'active':index===0}" v-on:click="select($event)">

                            <div class="information-slide">
                                <div class="img-block">
                                    <img v-bind:src="item.url_img" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="uk-container">
                                    <div class="title title-1">{{item.title}}</div>
                                    <div class="info-block">
                                        <div class="info" v-for="(iblock,ind) in item.info_block">
                                            <div class="incremental">{{iblock.incremental}}</div>
                                            <div class="description descr-1">{{iblock.description}}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="dotnav-block uk-position-bottom-center uk-position-small">
                        <ul class="uk-dotnav uk-dotnav-vertical">
                            <li :class="{'active':index===0}"   v-for="(item,index) in items" v-on:click="index_dotnav(index)">
                                <a href="#">Item {{index}}</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.14/js/uikit.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Велосипед не нужно изобретать, на вью давно есть готовые компоненты для слайдеров и галерей :) https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue

Comment: Мне надо будет просто анимацию картинки при смени допилить + цифры будет увеличиваеться с моментов возникновения слайда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно хранить индекс выбранного элемента(в данном случая с создал в data `selectedIndex`) и менять его. Для создания переключения слайдов через каждый 2 секунды я создал функцию `setMyTimeout`.

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: () => ({
            message: 'Hello Vue!',
            selectedIndex: 0,
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Center of osteopatia and rehabilitation',
                    url_img: 'https://i.imgur.com/gQp3VSW.jpg',
                    info_block: [
                        {
                            incremental: '+800%',
                            description: 'Increasing the number of transactions from organic search results'
                        },
                        {
                            incremental: '+240%',
                            description: 'Raising your revenue'
                        }

                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'SLide 2',
                    url_img: 'https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/space-wallpaper-5.jpg',
                    info_block: [
                        {
                            incremental: '+140%',
                            description: 'Increasing the numb organic search results'
                        },
                        {
                            incremental: '+790%',
                            description: 'Raising your revenue'
                        }

                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: ' SLIDE 3',
                    url_img: 'https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/4433836-space-wallpapers.jpg',
                    info_block: [
                        {
                            incremental: '+110%',
                            description: 'Increasing the number of trans'
                        },
                        {
                            incremental: '+99%',
                            description: 'Raising your revenue'
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }),

        methods: {
            select (index) {
              this.selectedIndex = index
            },
            index_dotnav:function (index) {
                this.selectedIndex = index

            },
            setMyTimeout () {
              setTimeout(() => {
                if (++this.selectedIndex === this.items.length) {
                  this.selectedIndex = 0
                }
                
                this.setMyTimeout()
              }, 2000)
            }
        },
        mounted () {
          this.setMyTimeout()
          
        }


    })
```

```css
ul{
        padding-left: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .img-block,
    section > *,
    .uk-slideshow,
    .uk-slideshow > ul {
        height: 100vh !important;
    }

    .information-slide .uk-container {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block {
        top: 50%;
        left: 95%;

        z-index: 2;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block li a {
        background: #fff;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block li.active a {
        width: 13px;
        height: 13px;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block ul {
        align-items: center;
    }

    .slideshow .slideshow-items > li {
        display: none;
    }

    .slideshow .slideshow-items > li.active {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .slideshow .slideshow-items > li img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <section>
        <div class="uk-child-width-1-2" uk-grid>
            <div>
                <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="slideshow">

                    <ul class="slideshow-items">

                        <li v-for="(item,index) in items"  :class="{'active':index===selectedIndex}" v-on:click="select(index)">

                            <div class="information-slide">
                                <div class="img-block">
                                    <img v-bind:src="item.url_img" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="uk-container">
                                    <div class="title title-1">{{item.title}}</div>
                                    <div class="info-block">
                                        <div class="info" v-for="(iblock,ind) in item.info_block">
                                            <div class="incremental">{{iblock.incremental}}</div>
                                            <div class="description descr-1">{{iblock.description}}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="dotnav-block uk-position-bottom-center uk-position-small">
                        <ul class="uk-dotnav uk-dotnav-vertical">
                            <li :class="{'active':index===selectedIndex}"   v-for="(item,index) in items" v-on:click="index_dotnav(index)">
                                <a href="#">Item {{index}}</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.14/css/uikit.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.14/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность!